# ReactJS view-source not getting update after changes in file

Tags: reactjs

I am working on ReactJS project, I need to add an H1 tag on the product page. **When I am adding it into the file it works in browser's inspect. But Whenever I am checking page source by CTRL+U, the H1 tag and its contents not getting appear.**

I really don't know what is wrong here.

I would appreciate any help from you guys.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your React code is executed dynamically so you won't be able to see your HTML Tag with view source.

- View source only displays what was loaded by the browser intially and does not take into account any JavaScript (React) modification to the web page that happened after the initial load.
- You need to use the inspect Tab to check on the current state of the page.
- Do yourself a favor and install the [React Dev Tools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools) to help you with your debugging.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, but the problem is when I am checking the page in SEO tag check tools, the H1 tag is not getting consider there. That is why I was thinking about view-source.

Comment: If you are concerned about SEO, you can do server side renders or trust the google bot will do the right thing. Please google 'React + SEO'